# How does JavaScript parse chained ternary expressions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary-operator

I'm reading through the jQuery [source code for jQuery.filter](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0d5ec2d8ac94a419ee47a39319c43ff9a7326b50/dist/jquery.js#L2672-L2684) and I stumbled upon this heaping pile of

```
jQuery.filter = function( expr, elems, not ) {
    var elem = elems[ 0 ];

    if ( not ) {
        expr = ":not(" + expr + ")";
    }

    return elems.length === 1 && elem.nodeType === 1 ?
        jQuery.find.matchesSelector( elem, expr ) ? [ elem ] : [] :
        jQuery.find.matches( expr, jQuery.grep( elems, function( elem ) {
            return elem.nodeType === 1;
        }));
};
```

So in short we have

```
return "a" && "b" ? "c" ? "d" : "e" : "f";
```

where each string could be a varying value

My question isn't how to decipher this code, but my brain is tying in knots trying to evaluate the logic being used here.

Can anyone help me understand how JavaScript evaluates this return expression?

Comment: It seems evident that `c ? d : e` **must** be a sub-expression (there's no other meaningful way to interpret those tokens).  Therefore it really comes down to whether `a && b ? x : y` is `(a && b) ? x : y` or `a && (b ? x : y)`.  But surely this is solved with a trivial Google search for "javascript precedence" or similar?

Comment: Someone in jQuery should learn to use braces though it cost 2 bits in the framework size...

Comment: Also, the code format actually makes it easy in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditional operator is right-associative and the logical operators have higher precedence, so this:

```
return "a" && "b" ? "c" ? "d" : "e" : "f";
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
return ( ("a" && "b") ? ("c" ? "d" : "e") : "f" );
```

Or in full:

```
if ("a" && "b") {
    if ("c") {
        return "d";
    } else {
        return "e";
    }
} else {
    return "f";
}
```

**Reference**

- [MDN: Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: Thanks, pony. You're a real pretty pony.